# React router paths

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to display a 404 page if the path in my web app is undefined or nothing is rendered due to something having been deleted. For example, users can create books and the books id becomes the path to that page. But if a user deletes that book, the path will be undefined. So, if that happens id like to be able to make sure that any other user that tries to go onto that page is shown a 404 message.
For example, a link could be
'/home/undefined'
or
'/undefined/books'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create any sort of "404 route", you simply have to add a route that matches any URL, and use it in a `switch` tag along with the valid routes.  For instance:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path ="/home" component={Home} />
  <Route path ="/home/book" component={Book} />
  <Route path ="/" component={FourZeroFour} />
</Switch>
```

You can also achieve the same effect by not using a `Switch`, and instead using `exact` on every route except the final one:

```
<Route path ="/home" component={Home} exact />
<Route path ="/home/book" component={Book} exact />
<Route path ="/" component={FourZeroFour} />
```

But what if you have a route that potentially matches both invalid and valid URLS, for instance:

```
  <Route path ="/home/book/:bookId" component={SpecificBook} />
```

(where `:bookId` *could* be `undefined`)

In that case, you'll instead want to check the URL parameter's validity inside your component.  For instance, your `SpecificBook` component might do the following:

```
const SpecificBook = ({ bookId } ) => {
  if (bookId === 'undefined') return <Redirect to="/404" />;
  // rest of component
}
```

You *could* also use `history.push`, but the `Redirect` tag will do more than just add a `history` entry; it will simulate a (server-side) redirect.

Answer (score 1):

I will check the book_id first and the redirect if not found.

```
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom"

function App() {

   const history = useHistory();
 
   if (!bookId) {
     history.push("/404");
     return null;
   }
   return <></>
}
```